# Javamail cannot connect to postfix localhost server

Tags: java, ubuntu, jakarta-mail, pam, dovecot

I am trying to connect to a local postfix+dovecot server using javamail.
I have connected to the server successfully using Thunderbird so I know that I have the username and password correct, but I always get

```
Javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed. 
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:661)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at servers.MailEngine.initMailServer(MailEngine.java:661);
```

The only thing that I know that I have done is change the java.security to disable some less secure protocols. what protocols does dovecot need? or am I looking the wrong direction with this.

If this is a protocol problem is there any way that I can pass a parameter to the compiler? I do have other services that I would like to keep from supporting the disabled protocols

EDIT:

```
Session emailSessionObj;
Store storeObj;
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.host", 127.0.0.1);
props.put("mail.imap.port", 143);

emailSessionObj = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
storeObj = emailSessionObj.getStore("imap");

storeObj.connect("127.0.0.1", 143, "username","password");
```

Here is the code that I used

And Here is the debug output

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
localhost : 143 : from@smsmail.pittsburgfoundry.com : smsmailpass:DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 143, isSSL false
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=localhost, user=from@smsmail.pittsburgfoundry.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A0 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Try setting `setDebug` to your session object to see if you can retrieve some more useful information.

Comment: The server doesn't like your authentication information.  Maybe some server log will explain why it won't let you login?  Also, note that you're using an old non-final version of JavaMail and you should [update to the latest version](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon I updated Javamail. Its clear now that My main issue is with pam authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end It ended up being a combination of an outdated javamail and some problems with my map authentication.

Another problems was that the username was enterd as xxx@yyy.zzz
and it simply wanted xxx. 
The debug message from dovecot and pam were too vague to be very helpful as it did not find a username